# referencing class from string value and query

Tags: android, database, string, class, android-intent

In my activity I need to call to query different databases depending on which one the user chooses.   Instead of calling each one individually I would like to have one code for a query and simply change the intent or class of the database from a string value.  Basically I need to change my database name reference from my class "EmployeeDatabase" to whatever database the user currently has selected.   I need to set the selected string x as class y and then have class y able to query.   I'm trying to explain to the best of my knowledge, sorry if it is confusing.    Thank you for your help!

Somehow I need to be able to set variable y as whichever class the user chooses and then be able to query like:  c=db.query(y.EMP_TABLE4, null,null,null,null,null,null);   It says EMP_TABLE4 cannot be resolved or is not a field.

How my database works right now with only one database option:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.redlight2);

    EmployeeDatabase db=null;

    try{
    ListContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    db=new EmployeeDatabase(this);

    c=db.query(EmployeeDatabase.EMP_TABLE4, null,
            null,null,null,null,null);


            mydisplayadapter4 adapter = new mydisplayadapter4(this, c);
            ListContent.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println("problem");}
```

How I want it to work:

```
     String x;

Class<?> y;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.redlight2);

    String x = "my database class name";

    try {

        y = Class.forName(x);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }



    // I want to replace everything that says EmployeeDatabase with y

    EmployeeDatabase db=null;

    try{
    ListContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    db=new EmployeeDatabase(this);

    c=db.query(EmployeeDatabase.EMP_TABLE4, null,
            null,null,null,null,null);


            mydisplayadapter4 adapter = new mydisplayadapter4(this, c);// OWN ADAPTER
            ListContent.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access various databases with all having the same schema ( from your code it seems like it is), then it should be very simple.

- Make a derived class from SQLiteOpenHelper.
- When you create this object, pass the database name. The other parts of the application do not need to know what database it is using.
- Also make sure to make this class a singleton. So you can switch to other database easily by closing the currently used one and then opening the new one.
- When you will be calling getWritableDatabase() for database operations from any place, it will return the correct db handle.

Comment: Thank you for the help, however I do not understand exactly how to get this working correctly.   I am pretty new to some of this.   Any simple way to call to a class from an interchangeable variable?

Comment: I figured it out.   I change the DATABASE_NAME with a interchangeable string from sharedpreferences.   ...Seems to be working very well.